# Java swing JTable doesn't show scroll bar when using JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I have a `tablePanel` which is a `JScrollPane`,and initialized with a `JTable`, the `JTable` initialized with a `defaultTableModel`．When I trying to add some rows to the table, but didn't see the scroll bar, appriciated for any reply.

```
JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

//rows will be added dynamically.
DefaultTableModel defautTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(null,columnNames){
  @Override
  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return false;
  }
};

JTable jTable = new JTable(defautTableModel);
jTable.setLocation(20,60);
jTable.setSize(950,450);
jTable.setRowHeight(25);

jTable.getColumn("No.").setMaxWidth(45);
jTable.getColumn("position").setMaxWidth(45);
...

JTableHeader jTableHeader = jTable.getTableHeader();
jTableHeader.setLocation(20,30);
jTableHeader.setSize(950,30);
jTableHeader.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 16));
jTableHeader.setResizingAllowed(true);
jTableHeader.setReorderingAllowed(true);

JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollPane(jTable);
tablePanel.setLayout(null);
tablePanel.add(jTableHeader);
tablePanel.add(jTable);

jFrame.setContentPane(tablePanel);
```

Comment: How are you doing that?

Comment: `tablePanel.setLayout(null);` is the primary cause of your problem.  A `JScrollPane` has it's own layout manager which is used to manage the scrollbars, view port and headers. `tablePanel.add` is your next problem, as you shouldn't be adding components to the `JScrollPane`, but instead, you should be setting the `JScrollPane`'s `JViewPort`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tablePanel.setLayout(null);` is the primary cause of your problem. A `JScrollPane` has its own layout manager which is used to manage the scrollbars, view port and headers.

`tablePanel.add` is your next problem, as you shouldn't be adding components to the `JScrollPane`. Instead, you should be setting the `JScrollPane`'s `JViewPort`.

But, since you're using `JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollPane(jTable);`, there's actually no need for the three lines which follow it.

I would highly recommend that you take a closer look at:

- [How to us tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Now, before you tell me how nothing I've suggested actually works, go and re-read [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) - this is the corner stone concept you will need to understand and master before Swing really begins to work for you

Comment: really thx for your help, and it works now. I feel sorry about my poor skills , I will follow your suggestions and take a closer look at those items you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

```
JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollPane(jTable);

// No need for the below code

/*tablePanel.setLayout(null);

tablePanel.add(jTableHeader);

tablePanel.add(jTable);*/

jFrame.setContentPane(tablePanel);
```